# spark history server crashing during spark-submit and spark-submit killed when history server active (standalone cluster)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am running Spark 3.1.1 pre-built for Hadoop 3.2 on a Debian latest Docker image with OpenJDK 1.8.0_41-b04 and Python 3.8.8 (built from source). All spark configuration options are default settings except the eventLog options:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled            true
spark.eventLog.dir                file:/tmp/spark-events
spark.history.fs.logDirectory     file:/tmp/spark-events
```

When starting spark history server I can reliably run pyspark code in local mode

```
spark-submit --master local[*] /usr/local/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

However, when I am trying to execute on the standalone cluster while the history server is running:

```
spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 /usr/local/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

The history server process exists without any message and the spark-submit command is "Killed":

```
21/04/18 16:38:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.28.0.4, executor 2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
21/04/18 16:38:10 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (172.28.0.4, executor 2, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4465 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
21/04/18 16:38:10 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.28.0.4:39975 (size: 7.8 KiB, free: 366.3 MiB)
Killed
```

After such an event no cluster execution spark-submits would work. However, stopping and starting the master again and **NOT** starting any history server will allow cluster execution again.

What am I missing - Why is the history server and spark job crashing silently, respectively where can I find out about the crashes?

I need the history server as it is presently the only integrated monitoring option using PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue above can be observed if the system resources assigned to the spark master are not sufficient.